# Failed redirect after mailing data from a form - stuck on script page, displaying zero

Tags: php, post, redirect

I succcessfully created a form to email a request for a quote for my company.  It works -- the data collects and is validated and the email sends. That page is at:

http://www.bardonsoliver.com/newbnocm/request_quote.shtml

However, I wanted a redirect to a thank-you page, at:

http://www.bardonsoliver.com/newbnocm/thank_you.shtml

At first, when I ran the form, it redirected fine.  Now I just get left on the script page with a zero displayed in the upper left-hand corner.

I had to change from "header" to "location" due to error messages.

This is the end of the script, directly after the code that creates and sends the e-mail:

```
if( $mailsend = TRUE) {
   unset($_GET['do']);
   printf("<script type='text/JavaScript'>location='" + $typage +"'</script>");
   exit;
} else {
   unset($_GET['do']);
   printf("<script type='text/JavaScript'>location='" + $retpage +"'</script>");
   printf("<script type='text/JavaScript'>window.alert('We are unable to send your e-mail at this time.  Please contact Ben through the contact page or try again later.  Thank you.')</script>");
   exit;
}
```

$typage is set previously, to:

```
   $typage='../thank_you.shtml';
```

and $retpage is:

```
   $retpage='../request_quote.shtml';
```

The paths are correct -- the scripts are a 'level down' from the main directory where all the pages are.

I'm a relative beginner with PHP and I am sure someone more expert than I will look at this and see the problem immediately.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should be doing this:

```
echo "<script type='text/JavaScript'>window.location.href='" + $typage +"'</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript as a redirect would work.. I'm curious what error messages you were receiving. I'm also curious how you're running php code inside a file with a .shtml extention - do you have you apache configured to run .shtml as php?

The easiest way I would see to do it is, after confirming your mail has been sent, using the following code:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

Comment: I tried using the header first, but got errors about how how they'd already been set. I got the alternative language here, IIRC.  Only the webpage (form) is .SHTML, btw. The file that gets run is "emailform.php".  It sends the message and then just sits there with the zero in the upper left corner and doesn't go any further.

Comment: Have you thought about putting your thank  you HTML on the php page that receives your form?

Comment: Barring that - I saw a comment on another page where they had 
exit(); after their header statement. That may be worth a shot as well.